# "Secondary" query

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL and I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to solve the following problem:

1 - I have a table with data about some people, including a name, a number code and a category for each one.

*Let's supose "JOHN DOE" is one of them, his number code is "1111" and his category is "A"; "FOO" is another one, with number code "2222" and category "B"; and "BAR" is another one, number code "3333" and category "A".*

2 - Everyone in category "A" was suposed to fill out a form which filled a second table in my database. In this table, the reference to the responsible for each answer is his/her number code. Each person could also answer the form more than one time.

**The problem is:** Now I need a table that shows me who answered the form and who did't.

**PS:** Let's call the database "data_base", the first table "people" (with columns "name", "num_code" and "category") and the second table "answers" (with columns "num_code" and "answer").

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be simply solved with a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    `num_code`, 
    `name`, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM `answers` 
        WHERE `num_code` = `people`.`num_code`
    ) AS `AnswerCount`
FROM
    `people`
ORDER BY
    `name`
```

There are a number of ways to solve this problem in SQL.  One of the advantages of the above result format is that you will get the number of answers per person.  Therefore if it is 0, then you know they didn't fill one out.

Comment: Good solution too. I'd replace `*` with `1` or `x`. MySQL is notorious for retrieving fields it doesn't need for the count if you use the asterisk. This is usually not a problem, but it may slow down the query if `answers` contains many fields or large fields like blobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a so called '[LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)'. It gets all records in `people` and links them to the records in `answers`. Then using the `where` clause, all records that indeed have an answer are removed from the result and only those who don't are returned.

```
select
  p.* 
from 
  people p
  left join answers a on a.num_code = p.num_code
where
  a.num_code is null
```

Another solution is to use [NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html). It is actually a bit cleaner to use that, but also a little more complex (you will need a sub-select). And it has proven (to me) to be slower in MySQL.